# aggregate within a week

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code to get data from a dataset

```
df = get(datetime(2022, 4,19), 'validations')
df.head()
```

The result is:

```
    card_id     route_id    timestamp
0   3941139920  34      2022-04-19 04:00:03
1   32111423    1305    2022-04-19 04:00:15
```

I need to aggregate the number of observations **within one week** from 19.4 to 26.4 per each route_id

i guess data from another day might be useful, so

```
    card_id     route_id    timestamp
0   40629176    2040    2022-04-20 04:00:07
1   1961463432  4003    2022-04-20 04:00:11
```

so the final dataframe that I need:

```
route id    trips
1           N  
2           N
3           N
```

Comment: All data are in one week? Do you need starting week by Sunday? Do you need grouping per `route_id` and week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need get counts per `route_id` and weeks starting by Sunday first get counts and then for aggregate per `route_it` use `sum`:

```
print (df)
      card_id  route_id           timestamp
0  3941139920        34 2022-04-19 04:00:03
1    32111423      1305 2022-04-29 04:00:15
2  3941139920        34 2022-04-23 04:00:03
3    32111423      1305 2022-04-25 04:00:15
4  3941139920        34 2022-04-26 04:00:03
5    32111423      1305 2022-04-27 04:00:15
6  3941139920        34 2022-04-25 04:00:03
7    32111423      1305 2022-04-21 04:00:15

print (df.groupby(['route_id', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='timestamp')]).size())
route_id  timestamp 
34        2022-04-24    2
          2022-05-01    2
1305      2022-04-24    1
          2022-05-01    3
dtype: int64

df = (df.groupby(['route_id', pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='timestamp')])
   .size()
   .groupby(level=0).sum()
   .reset_index(name='count'))

print (df)
   route_id  count
0        34      4
1      1305      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby and aggregate by time using [pd.Grouper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html), and you can find more details about other types of time frequencies [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='W'))['route_id'].count()
```

Comment: got an error (TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex')

Comment: @Semyon Ah, I missed the `freq` argument, updated my answer.